# Using Functions From Another Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to create a program with all of the UI files and the function files separate from each other in order to minimize the clutter.

My current problem is that I have a .py file (File A) with a class that has a function in it to create more labels in a QscrollArea based off of a list from File B. In File B, I have a function that will create the label names for the labels for the other function in File A.

The goal is for the function in File B to generate a random number, then turn that random number into a label in the GUI part of File A by calling the function from File A.

I can not figure out what to put for **self**=??? in File B when I call the function from File A, but I am unsure if that is my only problem.

In the code below, I do not show the code for the entire GUI, but I do have the container for the labels in my code.

File A

```
import File B

Class Test_Class(object)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(File B.mac_scanner)

    def discovered_macs_list(self, num, mac):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        print(num)
        label_id = (f"label_{num}")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 10))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255)")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName(f"{label_id}")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setText(_translate("Test", f"{mac}"))
```

File B

```
import File A
import time
import random

macs = []


def mac_scanner():
    while len(macs) < 50:
        rand = random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999999)
        macs.append(rand)
        File A.Test_Class.discovered_macs_list(self=??What Do I Put Here??, num=len(macs), mac=rand)
        time.sleep(.2)
        print(rand)
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to specify `self`, as it refers (as the name says) to the instance of itself, in the function `discovered_macs_list(self, num, mac)` the argument `self` is passed automatically, and that argument will be an instance of `Test_Class`, so for calling that method you will have to call it simply by doing this: `discovered_macs_list(len(macs), rand)` [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_self.asp) can help understanding the `self`

and you don't have to write `discovered_macs_list(num=len(macs), mac=rand)` as those arguments are positional argument, so they are mandatory and defined by its position. [this](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-optional-arguments/) explains more in detail positional arguments and keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good idea to have circle dependency as you have here. Try to structure your code in a tree-like fashion.

An example of this would be to have used `File A` in `main` and use a return statement in `File B` for use in `main` to pass into `File A`